# Optimizing GVim Fonts in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, fonts, gvim

I'm using *Tweak Tool* to optimize font settings like anti-aliasing and font-hinting in Ubuntu 13.04. While this affects everything else on my system, the fonts in the GVim window (the actual code) shows no difference.

How do I change the hinting or anti-aliasing settings for GVim (or whichever rendering engine it is using)?

Answer (score 1):

the only thing is you have to do it manually,:). open your GVim and then choose **Edit** and select **change font** option.

For more information & Credit : [wiki vim](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Change_font)

Comment: as I understand , If you apply fonts to system , the same fonts should be applied to GVim too. thats what you want , but we can not apply it automatically to GVim. we have to do it manually.

Comment: It's about the anti-alias and hinting settings I'm concerned with (not the actual fonts). The GVim window doesn't get affected by global changes I make to them (unlike everything else).